# Sorting roman numeral in java

Tags: java, roman-numerals

Input:

```
[IX, VIII]
```

Desired Output:

```
[VIII, IX]
```

The output of stage 0

```
[8, 9]
```

I create a function to return the decimal value of a roman numeral
then I have another function for sorting the numbers according to the increasing order.

I am stuck on the point of how to return the sorted decimal vector to the roman number.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
static int romanToDecimal(String romanNumber){...
}

static List<String> sortedList(List<String> number) {
    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
    int size = number.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        v.add(romanToDecimal(number.get(i)));
    Collections.sort(v);  //stage 0
}
```

Comment: Just to get this straight. Are you asking how to convert your decimal value back to a roman value?

Comment: Two options: 1. convert the sorted list of decimal numbers back to roman or 2. don't convert the list to a list of decimal numbers first, but sort the original list with an appropriate `Comparator` that does the conversion from roman to decimal and then compares the numbers.

Comment: Another option: use a `Map<Integer, String>` to map resulting arabic value to source roman value. Then sort the map, or use a map, which keeps elements sorted.

Comment: By the way, Romanian means "from Romania", which is not the same thing as "Roman". I took the liberty of fixing that in your question.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Comparator` util class to compare by the actual numeral value:

```
static void sortRomanNumerals(List<String> romanNumerals){
    romanNumerals.sort(Comparator.comparing(Main::romanToDecimal));
}
```